# How mahout user based recommendation   works?

Tags: mahout

I am using generic user based recommender of mahout taste api to generate recommendations..

I know it recommends based on ratings given to past users..I am not getting mathematics behind its selection of recommended item..for example..

for user id 58

itemid ratings

```
 231 5

 235 5.5

 245 5.88
```

3 neighbors are,with itemid and ratings as,{231 4,254 5,262 2,226 5}

{235 3,245 4,262 3}
{226 4,262 3}
It recommends me 226 how?

With advance thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `UserSimilarity` and the `UserNeighborhood` you have chosen for your recommender. But in general the algorithm works as follows for user **u**:

```
for every other user w
    compute a similarity s between u and w
    retain the top users, ranked by similarity, as a neighborhood n
for every item i that some user in n has a preference for, but that u has no preference for yet
    for every other user v in n that has a preference for i
        compute a similarity s between u and v
        incorporate v's preference for i, weighted by s, into a running average
```

Source: Mahout in Action http://manning.com/owen/